# MySQL -> PHP Array -> Json need output in array plus object format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i am trying to fetch data from MySQL and show it in JSON format
This is the partial PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT item, cost, veg, spicy_level FROM food1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo  json_encode($row),"<br/>";}
```

?>
i am getting output as

```
{"item":"dosa","cost":"20","veg":"0","spicy_level":"1"}
{"item":"idli","cost":"20","veg":"0","spicy_level":"2"}
```

but i need it as

```
food1:[
{"item":"dosa","cost":"20","veg":"0","spicy_level":"1"},
{"item":"idli","cost":"20","veg":"0","spicy_level":"2"}
]
```

can anyone please guide me?
i think what i am getting is in object format and i need output in array format i.e. with [ & ].
very new to this json and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incapsulate query results in array and after print it;

```
$sql = "SELECT item, cost, veg,     spicy_level FROM food1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$a = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if($a['food1'] ==null)
     $a['food1'] = array():
  array_push($a['food1'],$row);}


  echo json_encode($a);
?></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
$sql = "SELECT item, cost, veg, spicy_level FROM food1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$food['food1'] = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $food['food1'][] = $row;    
}

echo  json_encode($food);
```

Comment: sorry... it was typo... updated the code... change the last line

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `json_encode` each time through the loop. Put all the rows into an array, and then encode that.

```
$food = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $food[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('food1' => $food));
```